# Combobox de horários com intervalo de 5 minutos com PHP

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho um combobox onde pretendo armazenar horários das 07:00 até às 22:00 com intervalo de 5 minutos. Veja abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço isso no PHP? Infelizmente não tenho nenhum código pronto em PHP, pois não encontrei uma lógica.

```
<div class="input-group" style="width:100px">
  <select class="form-control" style="width:100px">
          <option value="">07:00</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #FAFAFA">às</span>
  <select class="form-control" style="width:100px">
    <option value="">07:05</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" name="Buscar" value="PorAcesso" class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$hora = '07:00:00';
echo "<select class='form-control' style='width:100px'>";
echo "<option value=''>$hora</option>";
for($i = 0; $i < 180; $i++){
    $hora = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+5 minute', strtotime($hora)));
    echo "<option value=''>$hora</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

O PHP nativamente já possui uma class chamada [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), e com ela é possivel realizar varias manipulações no objeto de data criado.

Com a ajuda de outro recurso chamado [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php), é possivel realizar essas modificações.

Para resolver esse problema, você pode criar um nó de repetição que vai adicionando 5 minutos a cada iteração.

Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
$hora = DateTime::createFromFormat('G:i', '07:00');

while ($hora->format('G') <= 22) {
    $hora->add(new DateInterval('PT5M'));
    echo $hora->format('G:I');
}
```

Nota: O código acima é apenas um exemplo, e não levará em consideração os minutos caso a hora ainda esteja dentro das 22h.